# How To Fix Audio Button Missing in the inspector After Play Mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in the main scene (canvas) in the canvas(setting button) and (panel)not active when (setting button)clicked (panel)activate and show up (sound button)when (clicked) sound on and off work perfectly.
the problem is when(panel) closed and transit from (main scene) to(next scene)and get back to (main scene)again the (audio manager) in the (hierarchy) missing(sound button) and if i select it when play mode is active its not there

here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class AudManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button soundBtn;
    public Sprite musicOn;
    public Sprite musicOff;
    public AudioSource _audio;
    public static AudManager instance;

    public void Awake()
    {
        MakeSingleton();

    }

    void MakeSingleton()
    {
       
         if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        } else
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
       
     
           
       
     }
     public void Start()
    {

        if (_audio.mute == true)
        {
            soundBtn.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = musicOff;
        }
        else
        {
            soundBtn.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = musicOn;
        }
    }

    public void SoundControl()
    {
   
        if (_audio.mute == true)
        {
            _audio.mute = false;
            soundBtn.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = musicOn;
            Debug.Log("soundBtn");
        }
            else
        {
            _audio.mute = true;
            soundBtn.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = musicOff;
            Debug.Log("soundBtn");
        }
    }
    
}
```

and here some picture ..

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Z position of the button? It should be set to zero. Also, the [near clipping plane](http://prntscr.com/nii9nq) should be set to zero (if it is in 2d)

If that doesn't work, try setting the order it appears in the background higher.

It could be just RNG if the background order is 0 and the Audio order is 0, it just picks whichever.

Comment: **Thank you for comment in the main scene canvas in the canvas setting button and panel not active when setting button clicked panel active and show up sound button
and when clicked sound on and off work perfectly
but the problem is when panel closed and transit from main scene to the next scene and get back to main scene again the audio manager lose sound button and if i select it when play mode is active its not there also like the picture**  
[link](http://prnt.sc/nikdwg)

Comment: any one have idea??!